# Issue with first top post display order

Tags: posts, sticky-post

Here i am trying to display top 6 post recent added post.But the problem is that first top post not displaying code is displaying top 6 post from top 2nd post except the top 1st post.

Bellow is sample which i have used to display sticky and post.

```
<ul>
<?php
**//To display sticky on top** 
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$sticky= get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

$args = array(
    'cat' =>255,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
   'post__not_in' => $sticky,
   //'paged' => $paged,
    showposts=>6

);
$recent= new WP_Query( $args);
**//End sticky**
**//Display top 6 post**
while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); 

$postvariable++;

if ($postvariable == 1) {
 ?>
<li>[widget id="text-8"]</li>  //short code  to display sticky news
<?php  
} else { ?>
<li>
            <div class="link_contect"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

            </div>
    </li>
<?php
}

?>
    <?php endwhile; ?> 
//End display top 6 post
</ul>
```

You can see this bellow snap top first not displaying in the news.after the top post there is one another news which is i have set as sticky.Actually i want to display that 1 st top post to to 5 post after sticky news.

[image: post]

you can check my output of current code which is ignoring the first top post.

[image: top post]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable $postvariable  in while loop skips, first post. Try this,

```
<ul>
<li>[widget id="text-8"]</li>  //short code  to display sticky news
<?php
**//To display sticky on top** 
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$sticky= get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

$args = array(
    'cat' =>255,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
   'post__not_in' => $sticky,
   //'paged' => $paged,
    showposts=>6

);
$recent= new WP_Query( $args);
**//End sticky**
**//Display top 6 post**
while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); 
 ?>



<li>
            <div class="link_contect"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

            </div>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?> 
//End display top 6 post
</ul>
```

Comment: while is not closed properly while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();

Comment: @SanjayNakate Any how you got idea, why first post is skipped right?

Comment: great answer from me 1++ ,i think the lope was considered the first top 6 post from the sticky post what you thing is there was any other isseue